# Android - how to implement a share button with a message?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a simple share action that would show the user a menu of Facebook, twitter, and email where they can share a set message I pre-set like "I am using a great app on http://www.xyz.com

What I have so far is the styling:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
          android:title="@string/share"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
</menu>
```

and I see many examples like this online:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

// Add data to the intent, the receiving app will decide what to do with it.
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, “Some Subject Line”);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, “Body of the message, woot!”);
```

But that just opens the email.  But how would I open that menu with all the possible places the text and link can be shared?

Thanks!

Comment: is there any facebook , twitter appplication available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But that just opens the email

Then either your timing of using this `Intent` is incorrect, or the only app on the device advertising support for `ACTION_SEND` of `text/plain` is "email".

> But how would I open that menu with all the possible places the text and link can be shared?

The following activity, from [this sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionBar/Share), run on my Galaxy Nexus, shows 8 possible sharing destinations, some built in (Bluetooth, Messaging) and some third-party (Remember the Milk, Evernote):

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
    ShareActionProvider.OnShareTargetSelectedListener, TextWatcher {
  private ShareActionProvider share=null;
  private Intent shareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  private EditText editor=null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    editor=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editor);
    editor.addTextChangedListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);

    share=
        (ShareActionProvider)menu.findItem(R.id.share)
                                 .getActionProvider();
    share.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener(this);

    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onShareTargetSelected(ShareActionProvider source,
                                       Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(this, intent.getComponent().toString(),
                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return(false);
  }

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, editor.getText());
    share.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
  }

  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                int after) {
    // ignored
  }

  @Override
  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                            int count) {
    // ignored
  }
}
```

Note that you need to call `setShareIntent()` on the `ShareActionProvider` when the text to be shared is ready. In my case, that comes from an `EditText` widget, and so needs to be updated whenever that text changes, which is why I have the `setShareIntent()` call in `onTextChanged()`.

Comment: thank you - looking into it and trying it...will report back in a few minutes with results :)

Comment: by the way, what is the SherlockFragmentActivity - should I also be using that?

Comment: @Genadinik: That is the base class for activities using ActionBarSherlock and the fragments backport. Since I am not using fragments here, `SherlockActivity` would work if you are just using ActionBarSherlock. If your app is only supporting API Level 11+, you'd use `Activity`.

Comment: for some reason my IDE does not recognize the SherlockFragmentActivity nor the FragmentActivity. Is there a library I need to add?

Comment: @Genadinik: Those are part of ActionBarSherlock. ActionBarSherlock is a third-party library, offering a backport of the action bar. You need to decide, **yesterday**, whether you plan on supporting API Level 10 (or lower), or not. *You should not be doing anything with `ShareActionProvider` until you make this decision*. Then, and only then, can you determine whether you should be downloading and using ActionBarSherlock or not.

Comment: well the app supports api level 4 and above. So is there maybe something more native I can use? I am also ok with this feature just not working for people with older phones.

Comment: @Genadinik: The native action bar is for API Level 11+. `ShareActionProvider` is for API Level 14+. This is covered in the documentation. You are welcome to just create an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` and use `startActivity()`, per StinePike's answer, as this will work for all versions of Android.

Comment: thank you for helping me. I am just a bit confused. Is the advantage of using the 3rd party library you mentioned that it enables sharing for people with earlier os versions? Sorry...confused :)

Comment: @Genadinik: "it enables sharing for people with earlier os versions?" -- no. It enables *you*, Mr. Genadinik, as an Android developer, to use `ShareActionProvider` going back to API Level 7. As I wrote earlier, **"ActionBarSherlock is a third-party library, offering a backport of the action bar"**. `ShareActionProvider` requires the action bar. You can learn more about ActionBarSherlock at its Web site (http://actionbarsherlock.com/). You can learn more about the action bar in the documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
String message = "I am using a great app on http://www.xyz.com"
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share with friends"));
```

Comment: actually I guess my confusion is with how to connect that menu xml to the intent.